# Why does Ubuntu terminal shut down while running load tests?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, load

Facing a peculiar problem when doing load testing on my laptop with 2000 comcurrent users using cometd. Following all steps in http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/howtos/loadtesting.
These tests run fine for about 1000 concurrent client.

But when I increase the load to about 2000 CCUs, the terminal just shuts down.

Any idea what's happening here?

BTW, i have followed all the OS level settings as per the site. i.e.

```
# ulimit -n 65536
# ifconfig eth0 txqueuelen 8192 # replace eth0 with the ethernet interface you are using
# /sbin/sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=4096
# /sbin/sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=16384
# /sbin/sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=16777216
# /sbin/sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=16777216
# /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=8192
# /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
```

Also, I have noticed this happened even when I run load tests for other platforms. I know this has to be something related to the OS, but I cannot figure out what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

ulimit command has been executed correctly? I read something about it in [Ubuntu forum archive](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-114071.html) and [Ubuntu apache problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1981187).